# Blender V2.78 - ERROR - OpenCL build failed: Errors in Console

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Hi I'm new to this forum, I've been Rendering my scenes in Cycles with CPU, and recently I've read that GPU renders are faster. After following instructions in the Blender Manual on how to Turn it ON, I turned 'OpenCL' on and set my scene to render on 'GPU Compute'.

I have Intel Core i5 with AMD Radeon HD 8500M and also downloaded the OpenCL 2.0 from AMD site. so I'm confident it will run.

Now, I'm getting the error "OpenCL Build Failed: Errors in Console. I looked at my System Console and it said:

---

```
Read new prefs: C:\Users\Aldwin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\
config\userpref.blend
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 48000hz, got 44100hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python
archimesh: Imported multifiles
version 3 imported
measureit: Imported multifiles
read blend: C:\Users\Aldwin\Desktop\Work\3D Models\Blender Files\PALMUS Concept
1 - Slim - Sharp - Stylish\PALMUS - ConceptualModel-01 v3 - 8 - CleanUp - Transp
arent Background.blend
Device init success
Compiling base_kernel OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: -D__NODES_MAX_GROUP__=3 -D__NODES_FEATURES__=4 -D__MAX_CLOSURE__=7
-D__NO_HAIR__ -D__NO_OBJECT_MOTION__ -D__NO_CAMERA_MOTION__ -D__NO_BAKING__ -D__
NO_VOLUME__ -D__NO_SUBSURFACE__ -D__NO_BRANCHED_PATH__ -D__NO_PATCH_EVAL__
OpenCL kernel build output:
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\k
ernels/opencl\../../kernel_projection.h", line 238: error:
          expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
                float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
                                 ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\Aldwin\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL36
72T1.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Build error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
Saved: 'C:\Users\Aldwin\Desktop\Work\3D Models\Rendered Animation Frames\PALMUS
v3\0047.png'
 Time: 00:29.29 (Saving: 00:00.37)

Device init success
Compiling base_kernel OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: -D__NODES_MAX_GROUP__=3 -D__NODES_FEATURES__=4 -D__MAX_CLOSURE__=7
-D__NO_HAIR__ -D__NO_OBJECT_MOTION__ -D__NO_CAMERA_MOTION__ -D__NO_BAKING__ -D__
NO_VOLUME__ -D__NO_SUBSURFACE__ -D__NO_BRANCHED_PATH__ -D__NO_PATCH_EVAL__
OpenCL kernel build output:
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\k
ernels/opencl\../../kernel_projection.h", line 238: error:
          expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
                float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
                                 ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\Aldwin\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL36
72T2.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Build error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
Error: OpenCL build failed: errors in console
```

---

Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem? I've already looked into this problem in other sites, unfortunately I think it doesn't cater to this problem.